# need group by Query builder query for school management laravel to get numbers of student in each class

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

[image]

I want to get numbers of student in each class. 
i used this query before.

`$group=DB::table('students')->groupBy('class');`

What will be the query for getting student numbers in each class? please help

Comment: `$classes=Class::withCount('students')->get();`

Comment: I have students table. all datastored there. now i want to get the numbers of students in each class from students table..

Comment: DB::table('students')->select('class', DB::raw('count(*) as total_students'))->groupBy('class');

Comment: thanks bro.it works...